# C# getting warning Extract this nested ternary operation into an independent statement

Tags: c#

I have the following in my c# code. Not sure why I get the warning saying not to use nested ternary. I dont find any issue with my below code. Can anyone please point me what am I doing wrong here?

```cs
private static Func<DateTime?, DateTime?, DateTime?> GetHireStartDate
   => (DateTime? originalHireStartDate, DateTime? positionStartDate)
       => originalHireStartDate.HasValue && positionStartDate.HasValue
           ? (originalHireStartDate.Value < positionStartDate.Value ? originalHireStartDate : positionStartDate)
           : (originalHireStartDate.HasValue ? originalHireStartDate : positionStartDate);
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no technical error with your code, it's just incredibly hard to read and understand. Warnings are mostly just recommendations, here it's recommending you re-write this into an independent statement for clarity. If you disagree, you can just ignore it or suppress the warning

Comment: If you're happy with the code then you should ignore / suppress the warning.

Comment: What is the exact warning message you get?